# Custom Buttons in ToolBar not responding to actions. Toast is not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-toolbar

I have a very basic application, and I'm trying to put a checkbox in toolbar .

This is how my xml looks :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="xxxxxxxx.xx.xx.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchET"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/favorite_toggle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my MainActivity I've set a simple listener :

```
 favoriteBtn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.favorite_toggle);

 favoriteBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    addFavorite(url);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "again changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    removeFavorite(url);
                }
            }
        });
```

When I click the checkbox, nothing happens, the checkbox toggles but I dont see the Toast. I see following messages in logcat

> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Can someone give me direction on what could be wrong?

Update: I think its just the toasts not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show toast you must use method show. So in Your code :

```
Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: ew .. yes I was so much convinced that something was wrong.that I missed that .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `.show()` method after to your Toast. So it would be like:

```
Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Without that method, your have just created Toast message, but did not tell system to show it.